# What is causing attribute error in loop and how to solve this

Tags: python, loops, attributes

I get an error I somewhat understand but could not solve with the resources I found so far. What I want to do is to have a simple loop that takes a url from a list, requests its contents, prints the output, and goes on to the next url.

```
f = open('urls.txt','r',encoding="utf8") #had to specify encoding because of error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3754: character maps to <undefined> 
content_urls = f.readlines()
f.close()

from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
for each in content_urls:
    time.sleep(1)
    scraped = request.urlopen(content_urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(scraped)
    print(soup)
```

A "list" as previously mentioned seems to be the exact problem:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'

First searches brought me to:
[AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout' - Trying to process multiple URLs with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884647/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-timeout-trying-to-process-mul)
[Python list object has no attribute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622806/python-list-object-has-no-attribute-error)
['list' object has no attribute 'timeout' and only prints first item in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106566/list-object-has-no-attribute-timeout-and-only-prints-first-item-in-the-table)
[AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049151/attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-timeout)

But by all means, I seem to be unable to implement those solutions.
Do I need to convert my list into a string? I did try so but it didn't seem to work out either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your `content_urls` is a list of strings. When you iterate over it then the `each` variable contains the current string. If there are no other errors, then change `scraped = request.urlopen(content_urls)` to this `scraped = request.urlopen(each)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the issue.